# counting together values of inputs with the same class, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to write a script to calculate working hours. I have a table with 6 possible amounts of hours which need to be added together in a field at the bottom.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="amount[]" class="countAmount"></td>
  <td>(...)</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="amount[]" class="countAmount"></td>
  <td>(...)</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="amount[]" class="countAmount"></td>
  <td>(...)</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Total: <span id="total"></span></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to get the values of the class `countAmount` counted together.

I have no idea where to start with the jQuery code. Everything I tried was useless, but the main problems are how to handle the empty values and how to handle the values as an INT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the inputs:

```
var inputs = $('input.countAmount');
```

To convert to numbers and handle blanks:

```
var num = parseInt($(input).val(), 10);
if (!isNaN(num)) {
    // It's a valid number, not blank, not "a" or "q", etc.
}
```

To loop through them, use `each`.

So:

```
var total = 0;
$('input.classAmount').each(function() {
    var num = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
        total += num;
    }
});
```

...since within the loop, `this` will be the `input`, and to get the input's value, you don't need jQuery, the `value` property is fine.

Then to put it in your `total` span:

```
$("#total").text(String(total));
```

Comment: I had to trigger it with a keyup function but now it works fine.. Thanks!